# arange: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a very simple code which just returns an array of x from 0 to 10 in increments of 0.1, but keep getting error:

```
    x = np.arange[[0,10,0.1,np.float]]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

results = {} # creating an empty dictionary 

f = open (r'D:\Work\Thesis\TEST_figures\telemac_comparison_1', 'w')

f.write ('Distance'+'Free surface')

result = [[], []]
x = np.arange([0,10,0.1,np.float])
print x
```

As you can see its clearly not finished but I wanted to get this line sorted now.

Comment: Why is the error in your title not the same error in your traceback? And why does your traceback in turn not match the code you claim to be running?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That error is caused if you pass in `np.float` as the second argument, first argument the list minus the `np.float`.

Comment: Ok my mistake, the first error i included (TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable) was from when i was trying to fix my code. Thanks for the replies guys, very useful.

Comment: @user3771983 in future, it would be helpful to ensure that the error you report, the traceback you provide and the code you post all refer to *the same version of code*. It is good practice to reduce your code to [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting, but you should do a final check of the code and post *that specific traceback* if the error persists.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass in a list, pass in *separate arguments*:

```
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1, np.float)
```

Demo:

```
>>> np.arange(0, 10, 0.1, np.float)
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,
        1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,
        2.2,  2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,  2.7,  2.8,  2.9,  3. ,  3.1,  3.2,
        3.3,  3.4,  3.5,  3.6,  3.7,  3.8,  3.9,  4. ,  4.1,  4.2,  4.3,
        4.4,  4.5,  4.6,  4.7,  4.8,  4.9,  5. ,  5.1,  5.2,  5.3,  5.4,
        5.5,  5.6,  5.7,  5.8,  5.9,  6. ,  6.1,  6.2,  6.3,  6.4,  6.5,
        6.6,  6.7,  6.8,  6.9,  7. ,  7.1,  7.2,  7.3,  7.4,  7.5,  7.6,
        7.7,  7.8,  7.9,  8. ,  8.1,  8.2,  8.3,  8.4,  8.5,  8.6,  8.7,
        8.8,  8.9,  9. ,  9.1,  9.2,  9.3,  9.4,  9.5,  9.6,  9.7,  9.8,
        9.9])
```

Incidentally, the error message in your question title is caused when you pass in a list as the first argument, `np.float` as the second:

```
>>> np.arange([0,10,0.1], np.float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'type' and 'list'
```

but the `stop`, `start` and `step` values are *separate* parameters in the [documented function signature](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

Your traceback *also* differs from the code you actually published; that's using *subscription syntax* (indexing) on the function object, instead of trying to call it. Don't use `np.arange[]`, it is a function object not a sequence.

Comment: Great catch on the error in the title. I think title and traceback and code being three totally separate attempts is a new record.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two attempts

1. `np.arange[[...]]` attempts subscription (c.f. list indexing `l[0]` or dictionary access by key `d['key']`), which doesn't make any sense - `arange` is a function; and
2. `np.arange([...])` passes a single list argument, when `arange` actually takes (up to) four *separate arguments*.

Instead, you should do either:

```
np.arange(*[...]) # unpack the list to separate arguments
```

which would be useful if you want to define the arguments once and use them repeatedly, or:

```
np.arange(...) # pass as separate arguments
```

A demo of the latter:

```
>>> x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1, np.float)
>>> x
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,
        1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,
        2.2,  2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,  2.7,  2.8,  2.9,  3. ,  3.1,  3.2,
        3.3,  3.4,  3.5,  3.6,  3.7,  3.8,  3.9,  4. ,  4.1,  4.2,  4.3,
        4.4,  4.5,  4.6,  4.7,  4.8,  4.9,  5. ,  5.1,  5.2,  5.3,  5.4,
        5.5,  5.6,  5.7,  5.8,  5.9,  6. ,  6.1,  6.2,  6.3,  6.4,  6.5,
        6.6,  6.7,  6.8,  6.9,  7. ,  7.1,  7.2,  7.3,  7.4,  7.5,  7.6,
        7.7,  7.8,  7.9,  8. ,  8.1,  8.2,  8.3,  8.4,  8.5,  8.6,  8.7,
        8.8,  8.9,  9. ,  9.1,  9.2,  9.3,  9.4,  9.5,  9.6,  9.7,  9.8,
        9.9])
```

In future, consider [reading the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) when trying to use a function.